# Return results that don't match in join SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Refer to this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8fe2a/13

I have tables

```
CREATE TABLE Figure(
MonthNumber varchar(10),
Code varchar(10),
Figure int
);

INSERT INTO Figure (MonthNumber, Code, Figure)
VALUES ('5', 'S', '25'),
('5','G', '30');

CREATE TABLE Other(
MonthNumber varchar(10),
Code varchar(10),
Figure int
);

INSERT INTO Other (MonthNumber, Code, Figure)
VALUES ('5', 'S', '25'),
('5','G', '30'),
('4','K', '40'),
('3','D', '20'),
('2','J', '25');
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM
Figure f1
RIGHT JOIN 
Other O
ON F1.[Code] = O.[Code]
OR 
o.[MonthNumber] = MONTH(GETDATE())-1
WHERE f1.[MonthNumber] = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Result:

```
| MonthNumber | Code | Figure | MonthNumber | Code | Figure |
|-------------|------|--------|-------------|------|--------|
|           5 |    S |     25 |           5 |    S |     25 |
|           5 |    S |     25 |           4 |    K |     40 |
|           5 |    G |     30 |           5 |    G |     30 |
|           5 |    G |     30 |           4 |    K |     40 |
```

However, i am looking for this month's results but to also include the people that may have had a figure for the previous months but not for this month.

Desired result:

```
| MonthNumber | Code | Figure |
|-------------|------|--------|
|           5 |    S |     25 |
|           5 |    G |     25 |
|           5 |    K |      0 |
|           5 |    D |      0 |
|           5 |    J |      0 |
```

I cant really work out what i need on the join. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify the expected result more please? As I understand it you want to show all the codes for a specific month. If that code had been filled in last month it will show the figure for this month and otherwise it won't show a figure. This however doesn't fit the expected result you showed.

Comment: why you have Figure in both table? i don't see why you need to have that in Figure table if you already have the exact same value in table Other. And if you also want the last month (which is 4) then why you also show Code D and J in your desired result?

Comment: I want it to show people from all previous months

Comment: I noticed that the value `25` for `G` in your expected output can you please tell where it comes from ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to want logic like this:

```
SELECT MONTH(GETDATE()) as MonthNumber, 
       MONTH(GETDATE()) as Code,
       f.Figure
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT code FROM Other) c LEFT JOIN
     Other o 
     ON c.Code = o.Code LEFT JOIN
     Figure f
     ON f.[Code] = c.[Code] AND
        f.[MonthNumber] = MONTH(GETDATE())
ORDER BY figure desc;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8fe2a/57) is the SQL Fiddle.  I didn't bother putting in the `COALESCE()` for the `Figure`.  `NULL` seems like a suitable return value.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT 
    O.* 
FROM
    Figure f1
RIGHT JOIN 
    Other O
ON 
    F1.[Code] = O.[Code]
AND 
    (
        f1.[MonthNumber] = MONTH(GETDATE())
    OR 
        (
            o.[MonthNumber] = MONTH(GETDATE())-1
        AND 
            f1.[MonthNumber] != MONTH(GETDATE())
        )
    )
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8fe2a/44